# CSS3 perspective not applying until after animation completes

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on panel that tilts (using CSS) according to how it is pressed.  You can see a working demo here (currently only implemented for Chrome):

http://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/4tXbZ/

The one visual flaw I've noticed is that the perspective is often not applied until after the other transforms have taken effect.  Is this a bug in Chrome?  If so, is there a workaround?

The phenomenon happens more frequently when the square is clicked near its edges.

Comment: I'm not really seeing that, using chrome. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` solved this problem.